# Deprecate normal argument name change in function signature?

Tags: python, arguments, deprecation-warning

I want to change the normal argument name in a function. For the function `func`, initially with signature:

```
def func(vect):
    /*
    code goes here
    */
```

And the new signature looks like:

```
def func(vector):
    /*
    code goes here
    */
```

Do I need to raise a deprecation warning if I make changes like just simple change in variable names in function signature which is *just* a *normal arg*, neither `*args` nor `**kwargs`. The main point being do I expect the user to be using something like `c = func(vect="lol")` in this code?

Comment: Generally, if you make a breaking change, you update the major version number. Then write in the changelog that you renamed it.

Comment: Artyer: that is my question. Is it really necessary to deprecate it? I know the deprecation process, but I want to know If I should deprecate it?